# "Fake" Things that are used in Experiments

Tags: experiment-design

What do you call the "things" that you used in experiment, but not in real life? Things that are made for experiment/simulation purpose. For example, phantom for human body.

Comment: What do you mean by "phantom"? Are you referring to the "mannequins" or "dummies" that are used in place of real people (e.g. in crash testing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the most general term, you would call it a **model**. An animal model, a mannequin that models human movement/bones/flesh/weight, a drug that models the effects of XYZ *in vivo*. Whenever we can't use/describe nature directly, we use/describe a model.

Comment: Yes! Model or mockup.